# Encountered Private variable mAudioManager is never assigned in my code

Tags: java, android

I created a global variable of `AudioManager` Class  and make it private, like this

```
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
```

so I tried calling the `RequestAudioFocus` method  with the `mAudioManager` within an if(); statement like this

```
if(Result == AudioManager.AudioFocus_Gain_Trasient) {
    mAudioManager.RequestAudioFocus
};
```

and pass in the necessary parameters but I have a problem

It keeps telling me that `Private variable mAudioManager is never assigned` and it's making my app quit on me

Please Help! what can I do?

Comment: Are you assigning any value to `mAudioManager` somewhere in your code?

Comment: The message is exquisitely clear--**you're never assigning it**.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple, the error has already mentioned the problem. before you do   `mAudioManager.RequestAudioFocus`, make sure that you assign the variable "mAudioManager" to and object of that type.

---

here is a link which could help you out.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks for the tips. I forgot to call the getSystemService method. Now I did and pass in the necessary parameters and it's working fine